# After a successful geth fast sync, Mist began to sync all the db again

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

After 3 days of syncing with geth --fast, finally I got the last block synced
I started Mist and it began syncing again from -3,800,xxx
The DB folders were correctly set - I double checked them. Where is the problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Mist is no longer an active project in the Ethereum ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have stopped geth when you restart it again it will start to synchronize some blocks before as a security measure in case of a chain reorganization. But it should be fast if you have geth switched off a short amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, as mentioned here https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Ethereum_Wallet_Syncing_Problems#Fast_Sync_Just_Completed.2C_Transitioning_To_Normal_Sync after fast sync starts full sync